# Weird date inserted into Hive table

Tags: mysql, hive

The table tom_date already contains this date '2014-06-01 00:00:00.0'
It has one column col1 as timestamp(with a single row always).

When I do run this query-

```
select date_add( col1 ,7 ) from tom_date
```

I get the correct result of old date added with seven days.

But when I try to insert it-

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tom_date
select date_add( col1 ,7 ) from tom_date
```

It inserts '1969-12-31 18:00:00.0' as the date instead! Any reason why it does that and how do I insert seven plus days to this date value?

Comment: I'm sure this is not related to your problem, but `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col1))` ... is there some subtle reason why that's necessary?

Comment: Sorry Brian, you are correct. I tried it without them and they are not needed at all. I have removed them in the question.